# Pattern Based Ontology Transformaion

Tags: ontology

Pattern based ontology transformation, where we have source ontology A, target ontology B and an ontology pattern P. Each time P is met in A we do the required transformation.

For example if the pattern was (this is informally written): "replace each two equivalent classes with a single one". We will search in A for each match(i.e. two equivalent classes) and replace them with one class in B. patterns are expressed using SPARQL.

I need this for the following reason: I was wondering if cardinalities in ontology can be included in a pattern. Actually I'm on an issue that uses ontology as conceptual formalization of relational data sources (DB entities and their relationships are represented as OWL classes & properties) and I want to apply some transformations to handle some situations (e.g transform many-to-many to to one-to-many) in the ontology, which needs handling the cardinalities in the ontology. Is this topic covered somewhere?

I know I can perform that manually using API, but I was searching for some formal way.

Thanks.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two options, for OWL anyway.

OPPL which is the Ontology PreProcessor Language was designed pretty much for this sort of thing. It is an SQLish interface which allows you to recognise patterns and update them.

The other is Tawny-OWL (which I wrote). It is a general purpose ontology development tool; it includes a query language which you can specify patterns in.

The former is more mature. The latter will, I think, be more extensible.

Comment: OPPL is mature in the sense that its development is currently stagnant :-) (disclosure - I'm involved in its development. There is little going on at the moment). Tawny-OWL is more active, so take into account when choosing which one to use.